# Oracle Cursor Unpivot

Tags: oracle, cursor, unpivot

I tried running this query but it does not finish executing, but when i tried running only the select statement inside the cursor, it works but for about 30sec.
Is there any revisions or enhancement that I could do to make the execution finish, any thought or help would be appreciated. Thanks! :)

Sorry for the long code :(

The function of this is to check all the volume columns in the volume_input_3yp table if it has a volume that is not 0, if it has it must insert the record(ebrom_id and period) to the hbrom_table, but if it doesn't have, it must not be recorded in the hbrom_table, that's why there's a delete script there to clean all those wrong record.

```
    -- This cursor retrieves all the incorrect entries in the HBROM_VOLUME table         that have all volumes equal to zero in the VOLUME_INPUT_3YP table

DECLARE
  CURSOR TYP_CURSOR
  IS
  SELECT EBROM_ID, PERIOD_FROM_ID
  FROM HBROM_VOLUME
  WHERE     EBROM_ID || PERIOD_FROM_ID IN 
            (SELECT EBROM_ID || PERIOD_ID
              FROM (SELECT EBROM_ID,
            (BASE_DV_YEAR - 2 + SUBSTR (PERIOD,1,1))|| SUBSTR (PERIOD,3,2)
              AS PERIOD_ID, INPUT_VOLUME
                 FROM (SELECT VI3.DATA_VERSION_ID, BASE_DV_YEAR, EBROM_ID, 
                       INPUT_VOLUME_1_01, INPUT_VOLUME_1_02, INPUT_VOLUME_1_03
                       FROM VOLUME_INPUT_3YP VI3,DATA_VERSION DV
                       WHERE VI3.DATA_VERSION_ID = DV.DATA_VERSION_ID) 
                       UNPIVOT (INPUT_VOLUME FOR PERIOD IN 
                                         (INPUT_VOLUME_1_01 AS '1_01',
                                          INPUT_VOLUME_1_02 AS '1_02',
                                          INPUT_VOLUME_1_03 AS '1_03'))
                 WHERE NVL (INPUT_VOLUME,0) = 0))
  AND DATA_KIND_ID = 2
  ORDER BY EBROM_ID, PERIOD_FROM_ID;

 BEGIN
     FOR TYP_REC IN TYP_CURSOR
     LOOP
    -- Deletes all the wrong entries in the HBROM_VOLUME table

     DELETE HBROM_VOLUME
     WHERE DATA_KIND_ID = 2 AND EBROM_ID = TYP_REC.EBROM_ID;

     -- Inserts the ebrom with the correct date in the HBROM_VOLUME table

     INSERT INTO HBROM_VOLUME HV (EBROM_ID, PERIOD_FROM_ID, LOCK_SEQUENCE,
                                  CREATION_USER_ID, CREATION_DATE, 
                                  LAST_UPDATE_USER_ID, LAST_UPDATE_DATE,
                                  DATA_KIND_ID)
     SELECT EBROM_ID, NVL (MIN (PERIOD_ID), 999999), 0, 
            0, ONLPG_UTILITY.F_GETGMTNOW, 0, ONLPG_UTILITY.F_GETGMTNOW, 2
     FROM (SELECT EBROM_ID,
          (BASE_DV_YEAR - 2 + SUBSTR (PERIOD, 1, 1))|| SUBSTR (PERIOD, 3, 2)
           AS PERIOD_ID, INPUT_VOLUME
            FROM (SELECT VI3.DATA_VERSION_ID, BASE_DV_YEAR, EBROM_ID,
                  INPUT_VOLUME_1_01, INPUT_VOLUME_1_02, INPUT_VOLUME_1_03
                   FROM VOLUME_INPUT_3YP VI3, DATA_VERSION DV
                   WHERE VI3.DATA_VERSION_ID = DV.DATA_VERSION_ID) 
            UNPIVOT (INPUT_VOLUME FOR PERIOD IN  (INPUT_VOLUME_1_01 AS '1_01', 
                                                  INPUT_VOLUME_1_02 AS '1_02', 
                                                  INPUT_VOLUME_1_03 AS '1_03'))) SRC
        WHERE NVL (INPUT_VOLUME, 0) <> 0
              AND NOT EXISTS
                         (SELECT 1
                            FROM HBROM_VOLUME HV2
                           WHERE     HV2.DATA_KIND_ID = 2
                                 AND HV2.EBROM_ID = SRC.EBROM_ID)
     GROUP BY EBROM_ID;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi APC, sorry sir, but it is formatted using TOAD formatter, 
i'll edit it and try to lessen the code. Thank you for your insight :)

Comment: @APC I'm truly sorry sir I'm new here. and didn't even consider investing time for my question, lesson learned, and thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah that's much clearer.  Alas, now the problem is that performance is pretty hard to diagnose over the web.  But at least we have a chance.

Comment: Thanks sir!, haha hopefully someone could give it a look and give me some idea on how to make it finish executing.